# Using a combination of SQLite and SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have ran into a problem. So I am trying to get data from my SQLite database based on the primary key and then I will display the row of data in separate textviews on another activity. Now, I have this working using Intents, but the problem is that I do not want to use "startactivity(intent)" for example as I do not want to go to the activity, I just want to send the data.

So, in context, I have 3 activities. the first activity the user fills in the information and click "verify" button(which saves to the db). this brings them to the second activity which will have an "Information" button on it and when this button is clicked on the next activity this is where I want to display the data I have retrieved from the database.

I have read and tried multiple posts, but does anyone know what the best option is for me to use? I am currently trying to use a combination of SQLite and SharedPreferences.

Code for activity 1 to get and save the data:

```
 Button Progress1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    Progress1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            res = myDb.getProgressBar1(); //gets the data from the database

            if (res.moveToFirst()) {

                String LTget = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("LINETYPE"));
                String PT = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("PACKAGETYPE"));
                String QTY = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("QUANTITY"));
                String DUR = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("DURATION"));
                String ST = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("STARTTIME"));
                String ET = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("ENDTIME"));

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                editor.putString(LTkey, LTget);
                editor.putString(PTkey, PT);
                editor.putString(qtykey,QTY);
                editor.putString(durkey, DUR);
                editor.putString(STkey, ST);
                editor.putString(ETkey, ET);
                editor.commit();


                Intent intent = new Intent(Dashboard.this, Actforfragmentname.class); //takes me to the second activity
                startActivity(intent);
```

Code to retrieve data: (unsure about getting from sharedpref so tried one line)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.verify_line);
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    sqLiteDatabase = myDb.getReadableDatabase();

    TextView LTTextView = (TextView)    findViewById(R.id.textViewspinner1);
    TextView PTTextView = (TextView)    findViewById(R.id.textViewspinner2);
    TextView QTYTextView = (TextView)   findViewById(R.id.textViewQuantity);
    TextView DURTextView = (TextView)   findViewById(R.id.textViewDuration);
    TextView STTextView = (TextView)    findViewById(R.id.textViewStartTime);
    TextView ETTextView = (TextView)    findViewById(R.id.textViewendtime);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String LT =(sharedPreferences.getString(LTkey, LTget));



    LTTextView.setText(LT);
    PTTextView.setText(PT);
    QTYTextView.setText(QTY);
    DURTextView.setText(DUR);
    STTextView.setText(ST);
    ETTextView.setText(ET);


}
```

Can anyone help me out??

Thanks

Comment: when you have stored in database then why using shared preferences. Once saved in database it doesn't matter where you retrieve it. There is no need to fetch it in second activity. You can directly fetch your data in third activity.

Answer (score 0):

You should use either Shared Preferences or SQLite database, the first one if you have a small amount of datas. The second one if it is bigger.

So You should push informations in database on button click in Activity 1, and retrieve them in Activity 3.

Comment: I am trying to use both. I have tried using just SQLite and it works when I start the activity to go straight to the activity where the data is retrieved but I don't want to view that activity straight away I want to go to another one where a button is pressed then it displays the activity with textviews to display the data

Comment: therefore, I tried to use sharedpreferences as well

Comment: I'm not trying to retrieve It in Activity 2. I am trying to retrieve it in Activity 3 but.... I must go from Activity 1, to Activity 2, to Activity 3. therefore, I cannot use startactivity(activity1, activity3) to send the data

Comment: I understand, but you can only startActivity() from 1 to 2, then 2 to 3. You do not send datas from an activity to another, you deal between Activity 1 -> database and then database - > Activity 3. It has nothing to do with startActivity(1 -> 3)

Comment: Yes so how do I display the data from Activity 1 that has been stored in the database in activity 3.. but by going from 1 to 2 to 3?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using the method that I was trying out and that was using both SQLite and Shared Preferences together. I had to change the line of code that I was getting the sharedpreferences so to retrieve the data I know have:

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);

    String LT = sharedPreferences.getString(LTkey, null);
    String PT = sharedPreferences.getString(PTkey, null);
    String QTY = sharedPreferences.getString(qtykey, null);
    String DUR = sharedPreferences.getString(durkey, null);
    String ST = sharedPreferences.getString(STkey, null);
    String ET = sharedPreferences.getString(ETkey, null);
```

Comment: but still that is unnecessary to store values in shared preferences when you have it in database